# Can we use inout parameters in a Objective-C block?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, swizzling

Something like this ?

```
^void (__unsafe_unretained UIViewController self, UIScrollView *scrollView, CGPoint velocity, inout CGPoint *targetContentOffset){
    // Something
}
```

or whats the alternative to using such paramrters.

Context:

I am trying to swizzle the `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:` method of the `UIScrollviewDelegate` but the last parameter `targetContentOffset` is an inout parameter. I am using https://github.com/JonasGessner/JGMethodSwizzler to swizzle the instances which expects a block to be used as a replacement method.

Code which I am trying to use...

```
[scrollViewDelegateObj swizzleMethod:@selector(scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:) withReplacement:^id(JG_IMP original, __unsafe_unretained Class swizzledClass, SEL selector) {
        return JGMethodReplacement(void, UIViewController *, UIScrollView *scrollView, CGPoint velocity, CGPoint *targetContentOffset){
            JGOriginalImplementation(void, scrollView, velocity, targetContentOffset);

    };
}];
```

Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: Yes, you can: Cocoa's collection classes have enumeration methods taking Blocks with such parameters. Does your code not work?

Comment: No, I get a compile time error

Comment: And what is that error?

Comment: Unknown type name 'inout'  :(

Comment: What happens if you remove the word `inout`?

Comment: The library compares the original method signature with the signature of the block and only goesahead with swizzling if they match. In this case the library expects 'N^{CGPoint=dd}' for the orignal mathod bu the block signature is '{CGPoint=dd}' which do not match and the swizzling fails.

Comment: I see...let me look into this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62292/discussion-between-mohkhan-and-josh-caswell).